# Firebase Crashlytics for iOS Custom Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

Is there any proper setup for iOS extensions?

I added another app with the bundle identifier of extension, but no luck.
Can't send any crash report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most iOS extensions the best place to initialize Crashlytics is inside `init()` on your extension's principal class.

However for security reasons, networks requests are initially disabled by default for Keyboard Extensions. In order to change that you will need to update `RequestsOpenAccess` to YES located under `NSExtensionAttributes` in your info.plist file. Then the user will have to "Allow Full Access" in the settings for your app, inside the keyboard category. This setting is visible only if the custom keyboard is switched on.

[image: info.plist]

[Apple docs reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsextension/nsextensionattributes/requestsopenaccess)